# Ignore NaN in MATLAB plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot

Suppose I have

```
A = [1 2 3 nan 5];
```

If I do

```
plot(1:5, A, 'o-');
```

I will have the blue part as below.

[image]

How to achieve the red part?

## Update

I am sorry for not making the point straight in the first shot, but **the `isnan()` method that helps skip those values is not desired**, because I need to plot many of those lines, some of whom have missing values (`NaN`) at some random locations. So I have to keep the x-axis consistent for every line. That is why I cannot simply skip `NaN`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not super elegant, but functional:

```
idxs = ~isnan(A);
x = 1:5;
plot(x(idxs), A(idxs));
```

Comment: Please kindly see the update in the question. Thanks!

Comment: This should work equally well with multiple lines (using `hold on` if necessary).  If it doesn't work, please add a concrete example to your question.

Comment: Oh yes, Sorry I am wrong. This works as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = linspace(1,10,10);
y = [1 2 3 nan 5 6 7 nan 9 10];
figure, plot(x,interp1(x,y,x,'spline'))
```